# Is it possible to determine Postgres write rate in writes per second by table?

Tags: postgresql, performance, statistics

In PostgreSQL is it possible to get an approximation of the writes to a table as a measure of time?

Specifically, I'm looking for an approximate of "writes/sec" to a given table.  I know I can get total writes (insert, update, deletes) from the stat collector, but there is no clear definition of when the stats "began" so that I can determine a rate.

Is there another table that I can apply to make this calculation?

```
SELECT relname, idx_tup_fetch + seq_tup_read as TotalReads,
    n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del as TotalWrites, 
-- (n_tup_ins + n_tup_upd + n_tup_del) / magical_seconds_column_that_doesnt_exist as WritesPerSecond
    *
from pg_stat_all_tables
order by totalwrites desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality in PostgreSQL itself. You'll have take a snapshot of the statistics tables regularly and compute the values yourself.

Note that with `track_io_timing = on`, you'll also get I/O statistics.

Comment: bummer, i'm accepting this answer but maybe someone has some ideas on lightweight solution.

Comment: It's not as bad as you think - there are ready-made monitoring solutions out there that do things like that automatically. To name an (open source) project I am affiliated with, have a look at pgwatch2.